# Why do some of the doors close rapidly?

Tags: star-wars

Certain Star Wars' doors close rapidly, almost instantaneously. Is this feature perhaps limited only to "blast doors"? Is there a canon reason provided for why they are engineered so?

[image]

They also appear to open slower than they close.

Other doors, such as the one below, do not close as quickly even though one might expect that they should.

[image]

Comment: Out of universe: doors open and close at a speed that looks cool and/or is useful to the plot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Looking at it from a military perspective, it makes sense to have doors which may have to contain explosions, prevent incursions, and/or slow attackers to be able to snap shut as instantly as possible.**

This is helpful when you are dealing with:

- Explosive decompression: keeping in air and crew is a priority so a door that is able to be closed in less than a second is an asset as long as no one is there when it closes.
- Boarding parties: As long as the door can be controlled from the inside, this is a great way to slow down enemies who are already moving through your ship. If the doors use command codes, it means your forces can move and they have to break down those doors.
- On military ships, fire is a danger and uncontrolled spreading fire an even worse one. These sealed doors appear to be just what is necessary to contain fire to an isolated area.
- Likely such doors are very expensive so would be restricted to certain areas of the ship which may require high security or high levels of defense.

Why would they be so slow to open?

- The mechanism which makes them quick to close may require hydraulic pressure to be withdrawn to open, so while they may be quick to close because they are always pressurized and ready for emergencies, it may take some time to reduce that pressure to open these doors.
- This is a single possible, in universe answer, there are sure to be many other potential reasons.

From Wookieepedia

> A [blast door](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Blast_door) (or shielded door) was a type of door found on many starships and high-security facilities. Blast doors were extra doors that were closed next to a room's regular entrance or other closed door to provide extra reinforcements against hostile forces such as explosives, powerful blasters, or even lightsabers. Blast doors could also be used to seal off a portion of a ship which has been breached from the vacuum of space.

Comment: Safety would be another reason for most doors to close more slowly.  Security and leak containment might also be reasons for slow opening. Tor the former, it would tend to slow down the advance of invaders; for the latter, it might reduce air loss when the door is opened to an unsealed section (e.g., if pressure sensors on the other side malfunctioned or some idiot used the override).  Fire safety is a big deal on any space vehicle/station, though a military one would have more opportunities for a fire starting.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton In the two screenshots in my question, the first is a control/guard room overseeing the hangar, while the second is an entry into the hangar itself. However, it is the first which is the faster-closing one, which, IMO, is contrary to expectations.

Comment: @coleopterist: The hanger has a force field that keeps air from escaping, and armed personnel close at hand.  It doesn't *need* a fast-closing door (it would close long before the hanger's air supply was all gone, if the field went down) but the control room is a security hardpoint - it needs to be well defended against incursion.

Answer (score 1):

Going off the two examples given you can see that in one there are personnel standing close to or even in the doorway as it is closing and in the other there are not.

Any reasonably advanced technology would be able to detect those personnel and alter the closing rate so as not to additionally endanger lives. Thus we can conclude that blast doors and doors in general are somewhat 'smart' and capable of reacting to the situation, almost as if they were being directed by a third party...

Not that safety systems seem, from a twentieth century perspective, to be an overriding principle in the Star Wars universe but maybe that's because they're so far advanced that we simply can't understand them.

Comment: I disagree with the sensor thing.  In Phantom Menace (yeah, I know, shut up) we see the door to Padme's office get triggered by a person with the enemy advancing.  It closes nearly instantly.  But there are people standing right beside it.